# Process switch and system level stack

Tags: operating-system

I am reading Operating Systems by Charles Crowley.

In the chapter 5 Implementing Processes, they have elaborated the process switching flow and stated few things about the system stack.

Unfortunately, I do not understand the working of the system stack.

**My Question:**
In normal programming, with every procedure call we save the PC on stack and pop it up after return. But in operating system environment, the book says that the system stack is re initialized to top of stack ( which means AFAIHU, deletes the history of calls to procedures).

Quoting from the Book:

> The operating system is written in a high level language. The compiler assumes that it is running a normal process with a normal stack. Since the operating system is different, we have to trick the compiler into doing what we want. We do this by re initializing and hence throwing away the system stack whenever we dispatch the process. The procedure call to the dispatcher inside the system will never be returned from, but the compiler sets up a stack frame assuming that it will.

Then how does it keep track of where to return. (when to return is the schedulers part AFAIHU).

Unfortunately in chapter 5, either they have not provided the correct context of the purpose of the explanation, or I have not read it enough number of times or I have serious trouble understanding it.

Please suggest, a simple explanation or reference to read from.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Economical with the truth' version:

When the kernel code is entered via a software interrupt, (system call), it swaps to the system stack to prevent the kernel stack overhead being inflicted on every thread. If the interrupt is of a class that may change the set of running threads, the kernel code saves the user-space thread stack pointer in the Thread Control Block associated with the calling thread - it has to since the kernel my well interrupt-return to a different thread stack, (depending on the interrupt request and internal state data).

Somewhere down the kernel stack, the scheduler/dispatcher decides what to to about the set of running threads and will want to set some thread running again, (maybe same one, maybe not).  It can easily do this by restoring the user-space SP from a TCB and performing an interrupt-return, so setting a thread running again.  The 'normal' system stack call frames are redundant, as you have read.

Unfortunately, there is a snag. The system stack pointer is now probably several KB down on its original position and, if nothing is done, the system stack will overflow after a few interrupts.

Of course, the code could go through miserable layers of time-consuming returns, before interrupt-returning to the user-thread, just to get the system stack pointer back up, but why bother?   Much quicker/easier/safer to just set it back up there so that the system stack pointer is at the correct place for the next interrupt:)

Hence:

> We do this by re initializing and hence throwing away the system stack
>   whenever we dispatch the process

A similar issue arises whenever the kernel is entered from a hardware interrupt/driver.

Comment: Kernel stack and system stack are not same :O . ??!!

Comment: Yes, usually same - my bad:(